# A ballpark figure on physicists

Tags: soft-question

EDIT: My question was off-topic.

Comment: People are voting to close because it's too broad but it's also off topic and, almost by definition, "primarily opinion-based." This question *may* (no gaurantees) get a better reception at the academia stackexchange, or maybe meta?? Anyway, there aren't too many actual physicists on here who are likely to spend the time to write a really good answer to this, but I hope you get one before it's closed. :)

Comment: Shortly: Way to many people (most people are not scientists by nature). It is boring (mainly because people around are boring). It is socially unstable. It is not well payed. Best days of excitement and sanity are gone. Now it is all about marketing. Read stories of great researchers of the past they ALL were working on THEIR own, not in universities or something. Academia was always unhealthy for young and still alive mind. I DODO have PhD FYI. Real science is a LIFESTYLE not a JOB - nothing more nothing less.

Comment: My short answers to the most interesting questions: 9) Yin and yang. Good days and bad. But mostly excited! In the theory realm people are coming up with really amazing things these days, and in the experimental realm there are surprises in condensed matter, and tense anticipation in hep. :) 10) I'm a Ph.D student, so only just getting started in real research... but it is very hard coming up with an original idea! That is, an original idea that stands a chance of being right, or useful...

Comment: cont. 11) It mainly affects how work is communicated to the general public. Good public outreach is an art and a (relatively new) science. 13) Only certain HEP experiments are really this demanding. There are many important smaller scale experiments that you don't hear about as much as the LHC or Tevatron. The situation is forcing experimentalists to become ever more clever (and they are rising to the challenge), but there is the real danger of more theorists going overboard with unfalsifiable claptrap...

Comment: 7 friggin' questions, each worth a Ph.D. in labor statistics. And 8 poll items, each worth less than a jug of root beer. How come this post has got 3 upvotes?

Comment: dj_mummy, what have you done yourself to answer the number-related questions? Have you looked at OECD stats? National Science Foundation publications? The question deserves a [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: dj_mummy: this site is not for OPINIONS. it is for objective, verifiable answers. Please re-read the [basics of SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/about). As for Africa, you can do a head count by looking at departmental-level websites. There aren't that many of them.

Comment: dj_mummy: here's a better idea for your poll. Scour through arXiv and physics journals, uni's and national labs' sites, get a 1000 address dataset, snail-mail  (or fax) out your questionnaire.

Comment: dj_mummy: why do you need random opinions from the Internet. How do you know you can trust **me** and my judgment? And soft questions need objective answers nonetheless, they simply don't require core physical reasoning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about sociology, not physics. It is also too broad. It is also opinion-based.

Comment: Besides the obvious reasons for it being put on hold, I want to note that I added a -1 to this question because of an inaccuracy: there are far fewer than 7 billion dudes in the world. I'm also hoping that the OP would be interested in knowing the number of non-dudes who have earned PhD's in physics.

Comment: Even with the edits it remains off topic because it is not about *physics*. For interest APS estimated that in the States fewer than one in seven graduating Physics PhDs will get an tenure track academic position or the equivalent (staff scientist) at a major public lab. A similar number applies to bachelor's degree holders in terms of having "physicist" or "scientist" in their mid-career job titles. For the most part the students we train go on to do *other* things with their lives. And this is not a bad thing.

Comment: does wolfram alpha answer your question ? .      http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+physicists . Unfortunately, it only lists those in the U.S. Multiply by 20 to get the world's.

Comment: @dj_mummy: Well, that's why I multiply by 20, and not 300.

Answer (score 1):

I can only offer you some figures I know: in the Netherlands every year around a thousand students start studying physics at the university. In a very crude estimation we can multiply this by 10 (5 years to earn a masters and 4 to earn a PhD) and say that if this number of enrolling students has been constant for quite some time, about 10.000 STUDYING (edit) physicists live in the Netherlands, which is about 0.06% of the Dutch population.

Remark:

-I recently read that the Netherlands is one of the European countries with the lowest percentage of science students, so the total percentage of the whole of Europe might be higher.

Edit:

-As mentioned in the comments I forgot the fact that the physicists continue living after studying. Assuming that a person finishes his PhD at his 30th and lives until his 70th (again, everything is very crude here!), and taking into account the fact the fewer people went studying several decades ago, I would say the upper bound is 0.3% physicists.

Comment: It seems to me that you are assuming in your calculation that all Dutch physicists die (or emigrate or otherwise stop being physicists living in the Netherlands) immediately after graduation.

Comment: @aufkag - the bit about emigration is worth exploring :P

Comment: @aufkag of course, you are completely right!

Comment: @Erik Of course. :) But, unfortunately, depending on how much "fewer people went studying several decades ago", your calculation still seems wrong. $1000\times 50 / 17000000\approx 0.3\%\neq0.1\%$.

Comment: @aufkag I was being very crude, but still your remark is correct, I changed it.